# Restricting Azure DevOps Repository access for specific VPN users?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, vpn, azure-repos

How can we restrict the access of the Azure DevOps Repository limited to the Azure Client VPN or any other VPN?

I have tried it using many different things like using conditional access, AD P1, AD P2 but I am not able to reach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to apply Conditional Access on your Azure tenant, and concurrently you will have to set the correct Azure DevOps policies, see the documentation: [Change application connection & security policies for your organization: Conditional access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-application-access-policies?view=azure-devops#conditional-access-policies).

> **Conditional access policies**
> Azure AD allows tenants to define which users are allowed to gain access to Microsoft resources through their Conditional Access Policy (CAP) feature. Through these settings, the tenant admin can require members must adhere to any of the following conditions, for example, the user must:
>
> - be a member of a specific security group
> - belong to a certain location and/or network
> - be using a specific operating system
> - be using an enabled device in a management system
>
> Depending on which conditions the user satisfies, you can then require multi-factor authentication or further checks to gain access, or block access altogether.
>
> If you sign in to the web portal of an Azure AD-backed organization, Azure AD checks that you can move forward by performing validation for any CAPs that were set by tenant administrators.
>
> Azure DevOps can also perform more CAP validation once you're signed in and navigating through Azure DevOps.
>
> - If the Enable Azure AD CAP validation policy is enabled, web flows are 100% honored for all conditional access policies. If the policy is disabled, Azure DevOps doesn't perform more CAP validation, but Azure AD always checks for CAPs upon sign-in.
> - For third-party client flows, like using a PAT with git.exe, we support IP fencing policies only. Users may find that sign-in policy may be enforced for PATs as well. Using PATs to make Azure AD calls requires the user to adhere to any sign-in policies that are set. For example, if a sign-in policy requires that a user sign in every seven days, you must also sign in every seven days if you wish to continue using PATs to make requests to Azure AD.
>
> For these third-party client flows, we don't support any MFA policies set after CAP validation. See the following examples:
>
> - Policy 1 - Block all access from outside of IP range x, y, and z.
>
>   - Access Azure DevOps via the web, the user's allowed from IP x, y, and z. If outside of that list, the user's blocked.
>   - Access Azure DevOps via alt-auth, the user's allowed from IP x, y, and z. If outside of that list, the user's blocked.
> - Policy 2 - Require MFA when outside of IP range x, y, and z.
>
>   - Access Azure DevOps via the web, the user's allowed from IP x, y, and z. The user is prompted for MFA if outside of that list.
>   - Access Azure DevOps via alt-auth, the user's allowed from IP x, y, and z. If outside of that list, the user's blocked.
>
> **IP-based conditions**
> We support IP-fencing conditional access policies for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
>
> If you find that your IPv6 address is being blocked, we recommend confirming that they configured CAPs to allow your IPv6 address. Also, it may help to include the IPv4-mapped address for your IPv6 address in all CAP conditions.
>
> Another issue we've found is that users may be accessing the Azure AD sign-in page via a different IP address than the IP address they're using to access Azure DevOps resources. Check your VPN configuration or networking infrastructure to make sure all IP addresses you're using are included within your tenant admin's CAPs.

[image: Organization Settings - Policies]